# Drop-down list reference in html

Tags: html, angular

I have a Sharepoint survey form that is built based on HTML and JS. However, the drop down list on `Area` is not working, and we suspect that is due to the code below.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <p>
        <div class="form-group row required">
            <label for="areaSelect" class="control-label col-md-2">Area</label>
            <div class="col-md-4" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : headerForm.areaSelect.$invalid}">
                <select class="form-control" id="AreaID" name="areaSelect" required ng-model="data.Area" ng-change="refreshCountries()" ng-readonly="data.IsSubmitted">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Please select an Area</option>                                       
                    <option ng-repeat="item in lookup.Areas" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option> 
                </select>
            </div>
```

We have no idea where to look.

Comment: The html code is fine. It is not in the html. If you run the html code from a plain html document it shows the selectbox perfectly.

Comment: Hi! I noticed you were using Angular, I have added the Angular tag for you so you can reach the right people.

Comment: Then what seems to be wrong? When we run it on SharePoint there was nothing under the drop down, does the {{item}} refers to the source? because we do have one file where we fill in all of the Areas and the drop down will update automatically based on that.